# Stop connection attempt immediately?

Tags: .net, sockets

Is there a way to make a socket stop trying to connect immediately? It seems if the socket tries to connect a dud it takes a certain amount of time to timeout on the connection. If the user clicks a button trying to connect, then wants to close, the other threads keeps the application alive because it is stuck blocking at the socket.Connect() method.

I have tried calling close from another thread. The exception changes but the timeout is still there. It is annoying to have to wait for the timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the async method [BeginConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginconnect.aspx) in conjunction with [EndConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.endconnect.aspx) to avoid blocking the main thread. As far as the timeout is concerned you may try to decrease its value.

Comment: @ Darin. I am looking at this but I am not sure how to stop the connection attempt. Is there not a race condition between stopping the connection and the connection being made?

Comment: @uriDium, you cannot *stop the connection*. It's just that the waiting will be performed on a separate thread. Remember that the timeout exception will be raised when you call the `EndConnect` method so make sure you handle it properly.

Comment: @Darnin. I see that EndConnect is blocking. So I still have to wait? Is there no way to get away from this waiting thing.

Comment: @uriDium, normally you call `EndConnect` from the callback which you provide to the `BeginConnect` method. So it won't block because the callback won't be invoked until the connection is established or an exception is thrown. And because this happens in a separate thread the application won't freeze while waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use async sockets? That way if you don't need it anymore, you close it and ignore anything that subsequently comes back on your callback. I'd expect it to be `BeginConnect` that you need to call.